# Symlink to bash starts some other shell

Tags: bash

In the following bash session, I have /bin/sh symlinked to /bin/bash. However, when I run /bin/sh, the result is not the same as running /bin/bash...any idea whats happening there?

```
benno@benno-laptop:~$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 2009-08-28 19:56 /bin/sh -> /bin/bash
benno@benno-laptop:~$ /bin/sh
sh-3.2$ exit
exit
benno@benno-laptop:~$ /bin/bash
benno@benno-laptop:~$ exit
exit
benno@benno-laptop:~$
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Invoking-Bash): "If Bash is invoked with the name sh, it tries to mimic the startup behavior of historical versions of sh as closely as possible, while conforming to the posix standard as well. "

Comment: This kind of invocation-name polymorphism is a rare but treasured part of the unix programming lore. Once you advance beyond casual use, you should be away of it. Another common place to see it is in the `grep`, `egrep`, `fgrep` family.

Comment: Busybox (http://www.busybox.net/) takes this paradigm about as far as it'll go :)